# Colored "(label)" for directories/virtual environments in WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I used to enter the pyenv and its version was in red "(3.x.x) on the left,   then, entering a specific folder the label was changed to the venv name "(venv_x) in blue.

Now I had to restart my work, but neither the python version is in red, nor the venv name when I get in there is blue.

Another point is that the blue env, thesis, was active when entering it.  Now it doesn't happen automatically and I have to  activate through `source /bin/activate` every time.

Could someone explain to me what the colored "(labels)" mean in Ubuntu/WSL and how to make a specific virtual env activate automatically?

[image]

Picture: In red on the left you could see what I mean with "label" inside the "()" and also that when `cd ./thesis`, it doesn't activate automatically and the label is not blue.

Answer (score 0):

The features you refer to are handled by your shell's (typically Bash, by default) prompt function.  The default Bash prompt in Ubuntu is fairly simple, including pretty much only your:

- User name
- The "@" symbol as a separator
- The hostname (on WSL, your Windows computer name by default)
- The current working directory
- A "$ " separator

So, for example:

```
salvo@Salvo ~$ <command goes here>
```

At some point before you reset things, you apparently installed a custom prompt function.  Most custom prompt functions have additional features like:

- Detecting when you are in a venv and displaying the name of the venv
- Detecting when you are in a Git repo and displaying information and status about the Git repo (e.g. the branch).

I typically don't run a custom prompt myself, so I can't tell you exactly which one you had installed.  I'll take a guess, though -- From the number of questions I see about it, I have a feeling you followed a tutorial of some sort when setting up WSL and installed [Oh-my-Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh) and the Zsh shell.  However, it could have been one of countless others.

The [Starship Prompt](https://starship.rs) also provides this ability for Bash.

Or the [Fish shell](https://fishshell.com), which is what I typically use, has a default prompt with these features.

Ultimately, to get back to the *exact prompt* you had before, you'll probably want to try to find the tutorial you followed (perhaps in your browser history?).  However, hopefully it's less important to you that it look *exactly* the same and more important that it have the features you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I didn't install a custom shell for sure. I think is a graphical mod of wsl, or something like this and I will search now something concerning what you wrote, because I want the detection features you mentioned

Comment: @SalvatoreSaladino As I said, it could simply be a custom *prompt* for Bash.  Do you recall making any edits to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`?  I can tell you that Ubuntu on WSL does *not* come with this feature by default.  It's also possible that something about the venv activation script you are using is triggering the custom prompt.  Are you using something like Conda?

Comment: It may be a lot of things, I'm totally new to this world and do things sometimes without noticing or remembering. I will search for venv custom activating scripts or some modifications in bashrc. I will continue searching on internet. just, do you know the name of that red write on my pic, the "label", so I can search for it specifically?
and thanks again for the answer

Comment: @PancakeBC That looks to me like it would be the Git branch that you are in.